# Naive Bayes Probabilities applying to Web Based Travel Recommender System

Tags: probability, naivebayes

Hi we're developing a **Travel Recommender System** and we stated that we will use Naive Bayes probability however we don't have enough knowledge in doing this.

We want to know the probability formula if the new user will choose the place that was chosen or rated by the existing user given that they have the same Gender, Age, Province and Traveler Style.

Demographics of User:
Gender
Age
Province
Traveler Style
Rated Places (Existing User)